# Conflict beeween JPA @Entity and Spring @Component/@Resource/@Configurable

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to Autowire a class which is annotated via `JPA @Entity`, so i added Spring's `@Component/@Resource/@Configurable` annotations but it will not allow me to autowire that class.

Is there any other annotation required ?.

Sample is:

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee{

   @Autowired
   TestService testService;
   ...
}
```

Where class `TestService` is annotated with `@Service` .

Comment: Request to person who downvoted, please give reason also.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but why would you want to do that? Hibernate should manage the lifecycle of `@Entity` object, not Spring, which is what `@Autowired` (together with other bean annotations) is used for.

Comment: I understand Predrag, but i have a requirement.

Comment: Agree with Predrag, why do you want to do that?? Any good reason? I am not the downvoter, but some suggestion is to add relevant code...  :-)

Comment: @We are Borg, My requirement is to get data from webservice on successful build of Entity, to achieve this i Autowired service into Entity class.

Comment: What do you mean by successful build of entity....It is annotated with at Entity, if there are no errors, it will be instantiated....You just have to get it.

Comment: I mean Entity class is instantiated.

Comment: You should absolutely not be doing this. You should be fetching the webservice data in your own service, **not** in the entity. In any case, the `@Component` annotation implies that the entity class is a singleton, and you generally want more than one instance of an entity...

Comment: Again downvoters please provide reason to downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that, make a constructor and pass the injected Service as perameter:

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee{

    Employee(TestService testService){

        //Do some work      
    }
   ...
}
```

now caller class..

```
@Service
public class CallerClass{

   @Autowired   
   TestService testService;

   Employee employee =new Employee(testService);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use @Configurable

```
@Entity
@Table
@Configurable
public class Employee{

   @Autowired
   TestService testService;
   ...
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable